# Getting unwanted space around contents of html

Tags: html, css, width, spacing

Contents of my webpage(be it header,menu etc.,) are not fitting into browser window.Below is the HTML & CSS code i have used

HTML

```
<div id="header">
</div>
```

CSS

```
#header {
height:150px;
width:100%;
position: relative;
background-image: url("top_frame.png");
```

And here is the output I get:

[image]

Comment: Where is the unwanted space?? Can you reproduce the problem in a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)? Would be very helpfull.

Comment: Thanks.Unwanted space was due improper margin value in the body style! Got it right as said by Srinivas Shukla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

in the CSS.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t07tccaz/).

I replaced `background-image` with `background : red;` for testing purpose as I didn't have the image

Answer (score 0):

Please use [Normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) before your custom css.